# Connecting Program to SQLite Database

Tags: java, sqlite

Hey guys I am making an inventory search program for a friend and am having issues with SQLite as I am new to this and this is my first time making something with a data base. I don't have anyone I can really show my code and I have just been putting this together following you tube tutorials and what not. If you guys could check this out and point out any obvious mistakes I may be making that would be great. I have included code that I got from a tutorial and the first method that I am trying to input data into the database with called "addVehicles".

```
    private static Connection con;
    private static boolean hasData = false;

    public ResultSet displayVehicles() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        if(con == null) {
            getConnection();
        }

        Statement state = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet res = state.executeQuery("SELECT sim, wo, description, oilN, oilB, "
                + "airN, airB, hydN, hydB, fuelN, fuelB, misc FROM vehicles");
        return res;
    }

    private void getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:SQLiteVehicles.db");
        initialise();


    }

    private void initialise() throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(!hasData) {
            hasData = true;

            Statement state = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet res = state.executeQuery("SELECT name from sqlite_master WHERE"
                    + " type=' table' AND name=' vehicles'");
            if(!res.next()) {
                System.out.println("Building the Vehicle table with prepopulated values.");
                //build table
                Statement state2 = con.createStatement();
                state2.execute("CREATE TABLE vehicles(sim varchar(100)," + "wo varchar(100)," + "description varchar(500)," +
                        "oilN varchar(100)," + "oilB varchar(100)," + "airN varchar(100)," + "airB varchar(100)," +
                        "hydN varchar(100)," + "hydB varchar(100)," + "fuelN varchar(100)," + "fuelB varchar(100),"
                        + "misc varchar(1000),");

                //insert sample data
                PreparedStatement prep = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO vehicles "
                        + "values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);");
                prep.setString(1, "101");
                prep.setString(2, "00000");
                prep.setString(3, "VEHICLE NOT FOUND");
                prep.setString(4, "N/A");
                prep.setString(5, "N/A");
                prep.setString(6, "N/A");
                prep.setString(7, "N/A"); 
                prep.setString(8, "N/A");
                prep.setString(9, "N/A");
                prep.setString(10, "N/A");
                prep.setString(11, "N/A");
                prep.setString(12, "TEST WORKED");
                prep.execute();


            }

        }
    }

    public void addVehicle(String sim, String wo, String description,
            String oilN, String oilB, String airN, String airB, String hydN,
            String hydB, String fuelN, String fuelB, String misc) 
                    throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        if(con == null) {
            getConnection();
        }
        PreparedStatement prep = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO vehicles "
                + "values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);");
        prep.setString(1, sim);
        prep.setString(2, wo);
        prep.setString(3, description);
        prep.setString(4, oilN);
        prep.setString(5, oilB);
        prep.setString(6, airN);
        prep.setString(7, airB); 
        prep.setString(8, hydN);
        prep.setString(9, hydB);
        prep.setString(10, fuelN);
        prep.setString(11, fuelB);
        prep.setString(12, misc);
        prep.execute();
    }
```

I am getting a ton of error messages such as

```
Exception in thread "``JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
```

Just got some new errors

> java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near ",": syntax error) at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:890) at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:901) at org.sqlite.core.DB.throwex(DB.java:868) at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.prepare(Native Method) at org.sqlite.core.DB.prepare(DB.java:211) at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.execute(JDBC3Statement.java:60) at application.SQLite.initialise(SQLite.java:47) at application.SQLite.getConnection(SQLite.java:30) at application.SQLite.displayVehicles(SQLite.java:17)

Comment: Just got some new errors     java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near ",": syntax error)
 at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:890)
 at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:901)
 at org.sqlite.core.DB.throwex(DB.java:868)
 at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.prepare(Native Method)
 at org.sqlite.core.DB.prepare(DB.java:211)
 at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.execute(JDBC3Statement.java:60)
 at application.SQLite.initialise(SQLite.java:47)
 at application.SQLite.getConnection(SQLite.java:30)
 at application.SQLite.displayVehicles(SQLite.java:17)

Comment: I'm thinking it may have something to do with state2 in my initialize method according to the errors.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41371446/javafx-exception-in-thread-javafx-application-thread-java-lang-runtimeexcepti may help your first issue

Comment: `+ "misc varchar(1000),");` has a trailing `,` which should probably be replaced with an enclosing bracket, `)`

Comment: Thank you MadProgrammer I fixed that and am going back through looking at other statements does the   PreparedStatement prep = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO vehicles "
                        + "values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);");
                prep.setString(1, "101"); etc. look like it should work? I am seeing different ways to add something to a table online. Should i leave the question marks and setStrings or just put what I want directly in the values brackets?

Comment: As an overall recommendations, [Using Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) is the correct approach, it's less error prone, protects against SQL Injection attacks and provides the ability for the driver to deal with any implementation details (like how date/time values are handled)

Answer (score 0):

Take you statement and remove all the "code" elements and have a look at it.  Go so far as even drop into the database console (or other DB app) and trying to execute the statement.

> CREATE TABLE vehicles(sim varchar(100),wo varchar(100),description
>   varchar(500), oilN varchar(100),oilB varchar(100),airN
>   varchar(100),airB varchar(100),hydN varchar(100),hydB
>   varchar(100),fuelN varchar(100),fuelB varchar(100),misc varchar(1000),

Immediately, I'm drawn to the last statement, which has a trailing `,`, but there's something else which is wrong.  If we remove all the "additional fluff" and have a closer look...

> CREATE TABLE vehicles(...,misc varchar(1000),

You will notice you're missing the enclosing bracket, `)` which should be at the end of the statement